# Junit "Class not found exception" in eclipse with the maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

When i run the junit it gives the pop up saying "do you want to proceed with the errors" and it shows the files in which there are error i resolved all the errors still the problem persist and shows the error below.

```
Class not found com.srv.impl.BulkSearchImplTest
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.srv.impl.BulkSearchImplTest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: Please post your code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion this is missing dependencies in pom.xml.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem on Eclipse Luna and I got my tests executable again by cleaning my project (Project -> clean -> select all projects).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should re-build the code before running:
mvn clean install

Comment: if so, could you find the related *.class file under target folder ?

Answer (score 0):

if you are writing unitcases for a project and all your test cases are in different project , you must change build path and add all project you are writing test cases for into Project tab  of built path , if that doesn't work , I suggest you clean project and build again.

Comment: junits are under the same project so need not to change the build path